# NSTextAlignment enum NSTextAlignment to different enumeration UITextAlignment

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am coding on Xcode5 for ios7 and the compiler shows this error:
Implicint conversion from enumeration type: NSTextAlignment enum NSTextAlignment to different enumeration UITextAlignment

```
-(void)setTextAlignment:(UITextAlignment)aligment
{
internalTextView.textAlignment = aligment;
}

-(UITextAlignment)textAlignment
{
return internalTextView.textAlignment;
}
```

Last line is the error on xcode5
Any help to fix this?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for the `textAlignment` property? Its type is not `UITextAlignment`.

Answer (score 8):

The warning tells you exactly what the problem is.  You're trying to assign a `UITextAlignment` enum value to a property of type `NSTextAlignment`.  Change your method to use NSTextAlignment enum values.  It's defined here: [NSTextAlignment](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSTextAlignment)

Comment: Wherever you are using `UITextAlignment`, use `NSTextAlignment` instead, simple as that.

Comment: I change it but appears: Conflicting return type in implementation of "textalignment" and also on the first line appears: Conflicting return type in implementation of SetTextAlignment

Comment: @javierfalbo Please, read some programming basics in order to understand what your compiler is trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

I got this warning in Xcode 5 because I was using a slightly outdated version of a 3rd party library called [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel). I just grabbed their most recent source code for their .m and .h files from their github page and pasted into those files of my project and all is good now. No more warnings.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and this did the trick for me as well.  Thanks Adam!